# how to give access to a perticular plugin page to a specific role based user in admin panel?

Tags: wordpress

i have developed a plugin where i have to give access to a specific role base user but i can not do that

```
add_action('admin_menu','pro_admin_menu_gallery');
function pro_admin_menu_gallery() { 
    add_menu_page(
        "Work Request",
        "Work Request",
        8,
        "work-request",
        "pro_admin_menu_list",
        get_site_url()."/wp-admin/images/generic.png"
    ); 
    add_submenu_page(
        'details',
        'Work Request',
        'Work Request',
        '8',
        'details',
        'pro_admin_list_site_gallery'
    );
}
```

i have tried this code but where i have to modify this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User levels have been [deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels) since WP 3.0. You'll have to replace `8` in your code with a capability that is associated with the user role that should have access to your plugin's admin pages. E.g. for admin users, you'd use `manage_options`.

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities